# RestKit: RKObjectManager getFirstElement

Tags: iphone, restkit

I'm using RestKit RKObjectManager in my app...To get all Objects RKObjectManager has `allObjects` method...But I need only first one...How to get first element from table ? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm puzzled. I looked at the [RKObjectManager](http://restkit.org/api/0.9/Classes/RKObjectManager.html) and did not find an allObjects method.

Could the class be something else perhaps?